# Convert all pcap file to csv with required columns python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, wireshark, pcap

I need to write all the output CSV files to a different folder. For example if `.pcap` files were in subfolders `Sub1`, `Sub2`. And `Sub1` has `a1.pcap` and `a2.pcap`. Sub2 has `b1.pcap` and `b2.pcap`.

I need my output CSV files to get written into a folder with the same names as above. `Sub1`, `Sub2`, then `Sub1` should have `a1.csv`, `a2.csv`. `Sub2` should have `b1.csv`, `b2.csv`.

How can I do that please?

I am getting the error below:

```
outputdir = startdir / "Outcsv"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

The code is:

```
import os
startdir= '/root/Desktop/TTT'
suffix= '.pcap'
outputdir = startdir / "Outcsv"

for root,dirs, files, in os.walk(startdir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(suffix):
            filename = os.path.join(root,name)
            output_filename = outputdir / filename.relative_to(startdir)
            cmd = 'tshark -r {} -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time_relative -e wlan.sa -e wlan.da -e wlan.ta -e wlan.ra -e frame.time_delta_displayed -e frame.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f > {}.csv'
            final_cmd = cmd.format(filename, output_filename)
            os.system(final_cmd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to recreate a folder structure at a different location you will need to ensure that the folders are created. This can be done using the `os.makedirs()` command. The subfolder structure can be determined by using any path deeper than `startdir`. This can then be appended onto your `outputdir` location.

The file extension can also be replaced by using `os.path.splitext()`.

For example:

```
import os

startdir = '/root/Desktop/TTT'
suffix= '.pcap'
outputdir = os.path.join(startdir, "Outcsv")

for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(startdir):
    for name in files:
        if name.lower().endswith(suffix):
            sub_folders = root[len(startdir)+1:]

            input_filename = os.path.join(root, name)
            output_path = os.path.join(outputdir, sub_folders)
            os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)  # Ensure the output folder exists
            output_filename = os.path.join(output_path, os.path.splitext(name)[0] + '.csv')

            cmd = 'tshark -r {} -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time_relative -e wlan.sa -e wlan.da -e wlan.ta -e wlan.ra -e frame.time_delta_displayed -e frame.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f > {}'
            final_cmd = cmd.format(input_filename, output_filename)

            print(final_cmd)
            os.system(final_cmd)
```

Comment: Martin would it be possible to help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182426/seperate-files-to-folders-and-sub-folders-using-python-script      I tried to change the code looking your code here, but no luck. need to recreate a folder structure at a different location. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Call [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), (something like this )

```
f_in = 'x.pcap'
f_out = 'x.csv'
tshark_template = 'tshark -r {} -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f > {}'
final_tshark_cmd = tshark_template.format(f_in,f_out)
```

Build the command dynamically using python, so you can control the names of the files.

Each `-e` stands for a field that you want to be in the output.

Comment: Thank you. How I can I get the same names as input pcap files and output csv files need to get saved in the same way as original pcap files were, with the same folder names and sub folder names. sorry I am new to programming. I dont know how to put all these into a python script.

Comment: the code works fine. But I need to write all the output csv files to a different folder. For example if .pcap files were in subfolders Sub1, Sub2. And Sub1 has a1.pcap and a2.pcap. Sub2 has b1.pcap and b2.pcap. I need my output csv files to get written into a folder with the same names as above. Sub1, Sub2. then Sub1 should have a1.csv, a2.csv. Sub2 should have b1.csv, b2.csv. How can I do that please?

Comment: @user3535695 modify `f_out` and make it include the folder name as well.

Comment: could you please see my updated code in the question. There are lots of pcap files I need to convert. So if I use f_in = '' then I can give only one name right?

Comment: @user3535695 It looks like you are in the right direction. All you need to do is to change the second filename in `cmd.format(filename,filename)` and replace startdir with outdir, and add the csv postfix to the filename. Makes sense?

Comment: @user3535695 see my previous comment. It point to code example

Comment: Assuming you use windows, your pcap folder is `c:\\pcaps` and the csv folder is `c:\\csvs` you would like to read the pcap file `c:\\pcaps\\x.pcap` and generate the file `c:\\csvs\\x.csv`. Do we agree on that?

Comment: I am working on linux though. yes that correct. And its same if there are other folders(subfolders) c:\\pcaps\sub1\\a.pcap then need to generate c:\\csvs\\sub1\\a.csv

Comment: `final_cmd = cmd.format(filename,output_filename)` should be modified to `final_cmd = cmd.format(pcap_file_name,csv_file_name)` where `pcap_file_name` is a composition of the pcap folder and the pcap file name it self and `csv_file_name` is a composition of the csv folder and the csv file name (here you replace x.pcap to x.csv)