# Separate csv files based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

There are few `csv` files in different folders and sub folders. I need to separate each `csv` file to incoming and outgoing traffic.

> if source == ac:37:43:9b:92:24 && Receiver address ==
>   8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a then those rows need to get written to .out.csv
>   files.
>
> if Transmitter address == 8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a && Destination==
>   ac:37:43:9b:92:24 then those rows need to get written into .in.csv
>   files.

The output files (files that got separated as incoming and outgoing) have to get the same name as input files (eg: if input file is aaa.csv then output files will be aaa.in.csv and aaa.out.csv).

And output files needs to get written into folders and sub folders as input files were. 
I tried the below code, but not working. 
I am new to programming, so not sure is this code correct or wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
import csv
import os
import subprocess

startdir = '.'   
outdir = '.'
suffix = '.csv'

def decode_to_file(cmd, in_file, new_suffix):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    fileName = outdir + '/' + in_file[len(startdir):-len(suffix)] + new_suffix
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fileName), exist_ok=True)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(open(fileName, 'w'))
    for line_bytes in proc.stdout:
        line_str = line_bytes.decode('utf-8')
        csv_writer.writerow(line_str.strip().split(','))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
    for name in files:
        if not name.endswith(suffix):
            continue
        in_file = os.path.join(root, name)

        decode_to_file(
            cmd= [if source== ac:37:43:9b:92:24 && Receiver address== 8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a],
            in_file=in_file,
            new_suffix='.out.csv'
        )
        decode_to_file(
            cmd= [if Transmitter address == 8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a && Destination== ac:37:43:9b:92:24],
            in_file=in_file,
            new_suffix='.in.csv'
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of Python's CSV library to process the rows and `glob.glob` could be used to walk over the files. `os.path.splitext()` can be used to help with changing the file extension. For example:

```
import csv
import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob('**/*.csv', recursive=True):
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    print(f"Processing - {filename}")

    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f_input, \
        open(basename + '.in.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_in, \
        open(basename + '.out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:

        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        csv_in = csv.writer(f_in)
        csv_out = csv.writer(f_out)

        for row in csv_input:
            if row[3] == 'ac:37:43:9b:92:24' and row[4] == '8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a':
                csv_out.writerow(row)
            if row[5] == '8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a' and row[6] == 'ac:37:43:9b:92:24':
                csv_in.writerow(row)
```

This assumes that your CSV file are in a standard format e.g. `aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd`. The `csv.reader()` will read each line of the file and convert it into a list of values automatically split on the commas. So the first value in each row is `row[0]`.

Comment: wondering if you can help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039336/convert-all-pcap-file-to-csv-with-required-columns-python

Comment: Yes, I'll have a look. Does this answer this question?  If so, don't forget to click on the grey tick to accept the answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: I accepted and vote your answer. Yes. thanks please let me know if you can help with the new question. Thanks