# Seperate files to folders and sub folders using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

In below code all the output files are getting written into T1 folder. How to separate those output files into sub folders, with the same name as original sub folders (where the original csv files were) ? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

path = '/root/Desktop/TT1/'
mystep = 0.4

#define the function
def data_splitter(df, name):
    max_time = df['Time'].max() # get max value of Time for the current csv file (df)
    myrange= np.arange(0, max_time, mystep) # build the threshold range
    for k in range(len(myrange)):
        # build the upper values 
        temp = df[(df['Time'] >= myrange[k]) & (df['Time'] < myrange[k] + mystep)]
        temp.to_csv("/root/Desktop/T1/{}_{}.csv".format(name, k))

# use os.walk(path) on the main path to get ALL subfolders inside path
for root,dirs,_ in os.walk(path):
    for d in dirs:
        path_sub = os.path.join(root,d) # this is the current subfolder
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_sub, '*.csv')):
            df = pd.read_csv(filename)
            name = os.path.split(filename)[1] # get the name of the current csv file
            data_splitter(df, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

path = '/root/Desktop/TT1/'
mystep = 0.4

#define the function
def data_splitter(df, name, dest_folder):
    max_time = df['Time'].max() # get max value of Time for the current csv file (df)
    myrange= np.arange(0, max_time, mystep) # build the threshold range
    basepath = "/root/Desktop/"
    for k in range(len(myrange)):
        # build the upper values 
        temp = df[(df['Time'] >= myrange[k]) & (df['Time'] < myrange[k] + mystep)]
        dest_f = os.path.join(basepath, dest_folder)
        if not os.path.isdir(dest_f):
            os.mkdir(dest_f)
        temp.to_csv(os.path.join(dest_f, "{}_{}.csv".format(name, k)))

# use os.walk(path) on the main path to get ALL subfolders inside path
for root,dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".csv"):
            filename = os.path.join(root, f)
            df = pd.read_csv(filename)
            name = os.path.split(os.path.basename(filename))[1]
            dest_folder = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filename))
            data_splitter(df, name, dest_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks. There is a small error. Let say inside TT1 folder there are two sub folders 'sub1' and 'sub2'. Inside sub1 there are folders 'sub1a', 'sub1b'.. and inside sub2 also there are folders 'sub2a', 'sub2b'. And inside those sub-sub folders I got the csv files. According your code only the sub1a, sub1b, sub2a,sub2b are getting created with the csv files. But folders above it Sub1 and Sub2 are not getting created. There are no csv files inside Sub1 and Sub2. But those need to be created. And inside those (Sub1, Sub2) only sub1a, sub1b, sub2a,sub2b  needs to be created with csv files

Comment: The method shown by Martin works fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039336/convert-all-pcap-file-to-csv-with-required-columns-python/57170835#57170835    but I don't know how to apply that for this question

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach should work here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

input_root = '/root/Desktop/TT1'
output_root = '/root/Desktop/T1'

mystep = 0.4

#define the function
def data_splitter(input_file, output_path, output_basename):

    df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
    max_time = df['Time'].max() # get max value of Time for the current csv file (df)
    myrange = np.arange(0, max_time, mystep) # build the threshold range

    for k in range(len(myrange)):
        # build the upper values 
        temp = df[(df['Time'] >= myrange[k]) & (df['Time'] < myrange[k] + mystep)]
        temp.to_csv(os.path.join(output_path, f"{output_basename}_{k}.csv"))


# use os.walk(path) on the main path to get ALL subfolders inside path
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(input_root):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.lower().endswith('.csv'):
            input_file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            sub_folders = dirpath[len(input_root)+1:]
            output_path = os.path.join(output_root, sub_folders)
            os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)  # Ensure the output folder exists
            output_basename = os.path.join(output_path, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.csv')

            data_splitter(input_file, output_path, output_basename)
```

This should result with the folder structure recreated at your output root folder.